# Norms and convergence in $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(O)$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $O \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be open, $K \subseteq O$ compact and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For $f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(O)=\mathcal{E}(O)$ we define

$$\|f\|_{n,K}^{(1)}:=\sup_{|\alpha| \leq n} \|D^{\alpha} f \|_{\infty,K} $$

and 
$$\|f\|_{n,K}^{(2)}:=\sum_{|\alpha| \leq n} \|D^{\alpha} f \|_{\infty,K}. $$

My first question: What is the difference between these norms?

Now I am not sure how convergence in $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(O)=\mathcal{E}(O)$ is defined. In my opinion there are three possible ways:

$(1)$ $f_j \rightarrow f$ in $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(O)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \, \forall K \subseteq O$ compact: $\|f_j-f \|_{n,K}^{(1)} \longrightarrow0 $ for $j \to \infty$

$(2)$ $f_j \rightarrow f$ in $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(O)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \, \forall K \subseteq O$ compact: $\|f_j-f \|_{n,K}^{(2)} \longrightarrow0 $ for $j \to \infty$

$(3)$ $f_j \rightarrow f$ in $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(O)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{N}_{0}^{d} \, \forall K \subseteq O$ compact: $\|D^{\alpha} f_j-D^{\alpha} f \|_{\infty,K} \longrightarrow0 $  for $j \to \infty$

Are these three types of convergence equivalent? What's the difference between them?

Comment: The $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{n,K}^{(i)}$ are only seminorms, not norms. The three conditions for convergence are all equivalent.

Comment: @DanielFischer They *are* norms, actually, because $||f||^{(i)}_{n,K}=0\implies f=0$. Sorry, I am wrong of course

Comment: @Vladimir No, there are nonzero smooth functions on $O$ that vanish identically on $K$ for any fixed compact $K\subset O$ (assuming $O$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$; if $O$ itself is compact, then $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{n,O}$ is a norm).

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes you are right of course; thanks

Answer (score 2):

1) These seminorms are not the same (supremum is not the same as sum), but (for the same $n$ and $K$) they are equivalent.

2) Accordingly, all three ways of defining convergence in $C^\infty(O)$ are equivalent.

Thanks to @Daniel Fisher for the seminorm remark ;)

Comment: Why are supremum and sum equivalent?

Comment: If you are in $C^k$, the norms are equivalent since
$\|f\|_{n,K}^{(1)}\leqslant \|f\|_{n,K}^{(2)} \leqslant k \|f\|_{n,K}^{(1)}$
but I don't know about $C^\infty$. Could you clarify?

Comment: Because the number of terms is finite and fixed. You know that the max and sum norm are equivalent on a finite-dimensional space. Use this fact to prove the equivalence here.

Comment: @frog note that you are actually in $C^k$ with $k=n$ when you compare these norms.